# Ignoring SYN/ACK

Tags: networking, tcp

A Mac OSX network client I'm working on sometimes having trouble connecting to an HTTPS port. Looking at the network trace, we're seeing this:

```
T0.0 client:port -> server:443 SYN
T0.1 server:443 -> client:port SYN, ACK
T3.1 server:443 -> client:port SYN, ACK
T6.1 server:443 -> client:port RST
```

The 3 second delay matches the TCP timeout for retrying on a failed SYN/ACK, so that's expected. But what is incredible here is that the client never responds with ACK or RST. When the client tries to login a second time, it is successful. This problem reproduces on many first attempts to connect. There are other HTTPS connections from this program going on at the same time, and they appear to be fine in the network traces.

My suspicion is that there is a race condition causing the socket to sometimes be incorrectly managed. But so far I've been unable to recreate this in any code but the impacted client (which is a very large and complicated piece of software). Even using `nmap` and `hping3` to hand-craft the packets, the client always sends at least a RST.

Is there any way to configure (intentionally or by mistake) a socket like this in userland code so it doesn't respond to SYN/ACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to configure a TCP socket in user land to ignore a SYN/ACK except to close it, which would provoke an outgoing RST in response to the incoming SYN/ACK. It is sounding like a kernel bug to me. I'm wondering about all these connections though. You should be making maximum use of HTTP keep alive to minimize the number of new connections per unit time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore the SYN/ACK because it is part of the 3-way handshake connection for TCP protocol. It seems to me that the problem is the server socket not being correctly open. Other hypothesis is server not being accessible (firewall blocking it, for example).

It's hard to give more help than this not knowing the program. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** check if you are correctly closing the previous client's sockets. It can happen the previous sockets not being correctly closed and the OS reaches the limit of allowed open sockets. In that case, an RST packet is sent.

Comment: If the server weren't accessible, then I wouldn't get a SYN/ACK from it. My problem is that *my* side isn't sending the required ACK (so obviously it is possible to ignore the SYN/ACK, despite the rules, because it's happening :D Reality always trumps specifications). Similarly if I ran out of sockets, I wouldn't send the initial SYN, but I am. My working theory is that I have to network threads accidentally using the same socket file descriptor to try to talk to two different server. I haven't been able to demonstrate what happens if you try that, though.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree with you. You can't ignore the 3-way handshake on a TCP connection! If you ignore it, then the connection will not be established. But your theory can be right: maybe you are accessing with concurrent threads to a same socket, on the client side, and one of them may be closing the socket, not sending the ACK and, therefore, the RST sent by the server. Try to check your theory (I don't know your program). In fact, the most usual cause for a RST is the socket being closed :)

Comment: I agree with the OP. The answer above is clearly incorrect. If the server socket wasn't correctly open it cculdn't have sent the SYN/ACK.